# readline keybindings in chrome/chromium

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, chrome, readline

Does a chrome/chromium extension exist that can configure often used readline keybindings?

Specifically `Ctrl+a` for `Home`, `Ctrl+e` for `End`, `Ctrl+d`, etc for use within a text editing box.

I have found several chrome extensions that allows one to configure shortcut keys to execute specific tasks such as selecting a tab page or opening a file, etc.

None have any provision for simulating another key (e.g. `Crtl+a` could simulate pressing the `Home` key), or for executing actions that pertain to the input field.

Comment: Do you want to navigate within a page, or more specifically edit text within a textbox?

Comment: edit text within a text box

Answer (score 0):

One chrome/firefox extension I find very useful is [Edit with Emacs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-emacs/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh?hl=en) which I used to replace "It's All Text" when it became defunct.

The extension adds a button to every textarea in a page, which when clicked on copies the current contents to your Emacs editor where you can edit it. When done the text is sent back to the textarea. I used it to create this answer.

It says it can work with other editors, but I don't have any examples to give you.